# Getting an import error after successfully gradio in some notebooks only but not in some ( especially new ones). Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, importerror, kaggle, gradio

```
!pip install  gradio
14 from pydantic_core import CoreSchema, core_schema
     15 from pydantic_core import validate_core_schema as _validate_core_schema
---> 16 from typing_extensions import TypeAliasType, TypeGuard, get_args, get_origin
     17 
     18 from . import _repr

ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeAliasType' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py)
```

typing_extensions is installed and its version is 4.9.0
gradio is successfully imported when i make a new notebook with same version of typing_extensions but it won't import in the notebook i want it to. It was not importing locally but it seems to be working locally. But it won't work on Colab and Kaggle Notebooks. I wondering what is the problem

Comment: Did you check the documentation here: https://typing-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#TypeAliasType. You could use Python 3.12 then you could import it from `typing`, otherwise you need at least version 4.6.0 from `typing_extensions`. It would be great if you could provide the output from `pip list`

Comment: the pip list on Colab is very long only things that my code imports explicitly are
!pip install -U -q google-generativeai
!pip install gradio

Comment: Which Python version are you using? From Python3.10 on, you could use the in-built `typing` module instead. From the information you provided, I unfortunately cannot offer you anymore help, as I do not have direct experience with `gradio` `google-generative-ai` on Colab.